# Do we browse "in" or "on" fullscreen mode?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> 1. Browse **on** fullscreen
> 2. Browse **in** fullscreen mode
> 3. Browse **on** fullscreen mode

I believe number 3 is incorrect. Can I use number 1 and 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one.

*Mode* is a certain style, way, manner **in** which a programme operates.

The usual preposition here is **in**.

> Sam celebrated **in fine style**.
>
> She smiled again **in a friendly manner**.
>
> **In some ways**, the official opening is a formality.

Comment: Does this mean "Always on fullscreen" is incorrect? It doesn't say fullscreen is a "mode" but thats obvious?